# Using List Comprehension for a number sequence (1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 .....) in Python

Tags: python

I'm doing exercise questions from A Practical Introduction to Python Programming by Brian Heinold (pg 83) and there was a simpler question:

11. Using a for loop, create the list below, which consists of ones separated by increasingly many
    zeroes. The last two ones in the list should be separated by ten zeroes.
    [1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,....]

```
# Question 11
L = [1]
for i in range(11):
  if i == 0:
    L.append(1)
  else:
    for j in range(i):
      L.append(0)
    L.append(1)
print(L)
```

15. Use a list comprehension to create the list below, which consists of ones separated by increasingly many zeroes. The last two ones in the list should be separated by ten zeroes.
    [1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,....]

I'm having difficulty with converting it into one line using list comprehension. Best I could do was

```
# Question 15
L = [[1, [0]*i] for i in range(11)]
print(L)
L = [j for row in L for j in row]
print(L)
```

Which would print:

```
[[1, []], [1, [0]], [1, [0, 0]], [1, [0, 0, 0]], [1, [0, 0, 0, 0]], [1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]
[1, [], 1, [0], 1, [0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 1, [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Flattening the list any further would result in a TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable and I would have to add another 1 at the end of the list using a seperate command which I guess would be fine. To add the code for flattening the list kinda goes over my head.

This is a second attempt using if/else statements, that gives the produces the same output and gives the same TypeError for when I try to flatten it completely.

```
L = [1 if i%2 == 0 else [0]*(i//2) for i in range(22)]
L = [j for row in L for j in row]
print(L)
```

I just want this as output:

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve it like this:

```py
L = [j for i in range(11) for j in [1, *([0]*i)]]
```

or

```
L = [j for i in range(11) for j in [1, *(0 for k in range(i))]]
```

**Edit**
I missed that it should end with a one. Here's a solution that does that:

```py
L = [1, *(j for i in range(11) for j in [*(0 for k in range(i)), 1])]
```

or with list comprehension instead of generators:

```py
L = [1, *[j for i in range(11) for j in [*[0 for k in range(i)], 1]]]
```

Comment: This won't *end* in 1. You can special case this though

Comment: So, you could do: `[j for i in range(11) for j in ([1] if i == 0 else [*([0]*i), 1])]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. I added a solution that ends with a 1.

Comment: All of the solutions so far build increasingly long lists from which `j` is pulled.  I have a preference for  `itertools.chain((1,), itertools.repeat(0, i))` which doesn't have to build the lists.

Comment: @md2perpe thanks! i just dont get the the part with the *, where you put *([0]*i)] the first asterisk is from my understanding preventing it from becoming a two-dimensional list. I just don't know what it means or represents, I can't find anything related to this in my book or any other reference material.

Comment: @WaleedMalik. No, the `*` makes the values from the following iterable (e.g. a generator expression, a list or a tuple) be used as values in the list. Example: `[*range(7), *range(5)]` gives `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: The "solution" in your Edit doesn't have any list comprehension, so it's not really a solution, as that's a requirement. Here are two: `[j for i in range(-1, 11) for j in [*([0]*i), 1]]` and `[j for i in range(12) for j in [1, *(i%11*[0])]]`

Comment: Or @juanpa.arrivillaga's attempt but with `[1, 1]` instead of `[1]`, as it's missing a starting `1`. (I like my first one best, btw... partly to show the usefulness of negative numbers :-)

Comment: @KellyBundy. I've added a version where I use list comprehensions instead of generators.

Comment: Hmm, I guess technically that counts, though I suspect the intention was that the list comprehension builds the result list rather than just a list used in the process. Otherwise they could just use their original loop-solution and replace `[1]` with `[x for x in [1]]`...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a nested comprehension that produces an increasing number of values that you convert to 0s and 1s by returning 0s for all but the last of each group:

```
n = 10
r = [1]+[b//z for z in range(1,n+2) for b in range(1,z+1)]
print(r)
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

If you want to avoid the need to add the initial `[1]`, you could use a similar approach starting z at -1 instead of 1:

```
r = [ 1-(b<z) for z in range(-1,n+1) for b in range(z+1 or 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not allowed in the problem, but assume we can use `math` library, there's a really interesting solution that goes like this:

```py
from math import sqrt, floor

print([1] + [1 * ((-1+sqrt(1+8*i))/2 > 0 and floor((-1+sqrt(1+8*i))/2) == (-1+sqrt(1+8*i))/2 or (-1-sqrt(1+8*i))/2 > 0 and floor((-1-sqrt(1+8*i))/2) == (-1-sqrt(1+8*i))/2) for i in range(1, 67)])
```

The key observation is that all ones in the target list has an index that's a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) except for the one on index 0(no pun intended). So we can just check if the current index is a triangular number.

The `nth` triangular number can be expressed as:

[image: Expression for the nth triangular number]

Let i be the current index we are checking. All we need to do is to solve:

[image]

And check if one of the roots is a natural number.

Again, I know this is not a valid answer. I just want to show it as the idea is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

p=[]

for i in range(11):

```
p.append(1)

for j in range(i):

    p.append(i*0)
```

print(p)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).